# Add .net-Core F# File to F# project in vscode

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, ionide

I am currently trying to add an F# file to an F# project in VSCode using .NET core. I have ionide installed and tried using the "Add Current File to Project" command, after creating a new file with the .fs extension, but this did not work.

Is there some setup for Ionide that I am missing? Or is there another tool I should be using?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just edit the project file by hand?

Comment: +1 for above comment, new fsproj format is quite simple. So you can just edit it, that said, the add file command should work as well, so if it doesn't maybe file a bug report with a repro.

Comment: Sometimes `F#: Clear Cache` also helps.

Comment: Please note that the order of files in ItemGroup in .fsproj is important.

Comment: I had heard that the order was important. May I ask what order files are supposed to be loaded in the fsproj?

Comment: @Daniel the order of dependencies, i.e. if file A contains say class A and file B function bar with parameter of type A, file A needs to go before B.

Answer (score 0):

To add the file to the project by hand you can:

1- create you file, myfile.fs

2- add the file to the myproject.fsproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>client_api</RootNamespace>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Complie Include="myfile.fs"/> 
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Open the file namespace on the main project and run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following directory tree:

```sh
.
├── MyFSharpApp.fsproj
└── Program.fs
```

Add we want to add the file `DB.fs` to get the following tree:

```sh
.
├── DB.fs
├── MyFSharpApp.fsproj
└── Program.fs
```

To do that we need to perform the following steps:

1. Create the file `DB.fs`

```ml
module DB

type Repository(databaseUrl: string) =
    let databaseUrl = databaseUrl

    member this.xxx() = 3
```

2. Reference `DB.fs` in `MyFSharpApp.fsproj`. We need to reference `DB.fs` before `Program.fs`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DB.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

3. Use our new module in `Program.fs`

```ml
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let repository = DB.Repository("someUrl")
    printfn "A string: %i" (repository.xxx())
    0 // return an integer exit code
```